# Error DatePipe Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, data, datepicker, timestamp

Acabei de atualizar minha aplicação de Angular 5 para Angular 6.

Ao salvar um registro no banco de dados Firebase utilizando **mat-datepicker** verificando no banco de dados notei que está salvando corretamente a data com o tipo **timestamp**.

data_nascimento: **(12 de julho de 2018 00:00:00 UTC-3)**.

Ao listar os registros não consigo usar o PipeDate do Angular porque está ocorrendo erro, pois está retornando do banco de dados **(Timestamp(seconds=1531..** na coluna data_nascimento no **mat-table**;

Antes de fazer essa atualização para o Angular 6, eu simplesmente estava salvando o objeto **Date()** que o **mat-datepicker** criava e no **mat-table** conseguia fazer **{{ data_nascimento | date }}** normalmente.

Em meu **app.module.ts:** estou definindo o **LOCALE_ID**;

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(localePt);

providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' },
]
```

Já tentei remover LOCALE_ID deixando o padrão, mas mesmo assim não está funcionando corretamente, ao retornar o objeto **Date()** que o **mat-date-picker** cria no banco, não é exibido a data no **input** ou no **mat-table**;

Não sei se isso é alguma mudança do Firebase ou do Angular, não sei o que fazer pois não estou conseguindo mostrar a **data_nascimento** no **mat-table** e nem no **form**.

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou converter no Angular a data recebida passando dentro de um `new Date()`? Eu já fiz isso várias vezes e funcionou.

Outra coisa também, eu importo direto o core pra usar o Locale:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from "@angular/core";
```

Tenta aí alguma dessas opções. Pra mim funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

No seu `app.module.ts`, adicione isso:

```ts
...

import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(localePt);

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "pt-BR" }
  ]
})
```